# Create random Wallet with connection to a specific provider via ethers.js

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, ethers.js

## Problem

I am trying to create random wallets via the function `Ethers.Wallet.createRandom` with a connection to a specific network (like [Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/) for example). The [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet-createRandom) specify that I can pass an optional `options` *object*.

## What I tried

I tried passing a connection to the network like this:

```
const networkProvider = await new Ethers.getDefaultProvider(process.env.NETWORK);
const wallet = Ethers.Wallet.createRandom({ provider: networkProvider });
```

Unfortunately, that did not work.

## Question

Is there an option to pass the network when creating the wallet or has this to be done later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned Wallet object ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet)) contains the private key and the address of the wallet. However, the address generating algorithm is **universal** across all networks. So if a private key `0x123` generates an address `0x456`, you can always use the same `0x123` private key to sign transactions from `0x456` address on all networks - the mainnet, Ropsten, Rinkeby, etc.

The network on which you broadcast the transaction depends on what network is your **provider** connected to. So if your want to limit on what networks the app can send transactions, you need to validate the provider's `getNetwork()` returned value ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getNetwork)).

Ad the `options` param: In the `createRandom()` [source code](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/wallet/src.ts/index.ts#L169), it only uses the param to affect the pseudo-randomness of how the private key is generated. But again, it's not related to the network(s) on which you're going to be using the wallet.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

setWallet(ethers.Wallet.createRandom(['21321']));
```

Options of `createRandom` may have the properties:

`extraEntropy` — additional entropy to stir into the random source